# Alternative to passing Greater Than sign as an argument

Tags: python

My function :

```
def check(list,num):

  check if there is list[x] > list[0]+num  # in case num is positive
  OR if there is list[x] < list[0]+num  # in case num is negative
```

So I can send 50 to check if we are up 50, or -50 to check if we are down 50.

The only way I see to do this is ugly :

```
  for x in list:
    if num > 0 :
       if x > list[0] + num : do something
    if num < 0 :
       if x < list[0] + num : do something
```

Since i can not send `>` as an argument and use a single line, I am looking for a more **elegant** way.

Comment: Of course you can send `>` as an argument if you use the `operator` lib. ie `from operator import gt`

Comment: @scotscotmcc your offer is mathematically wrong.. if num=-10 and list[0] is 100, then X should be < 90. I need to do DIFFERENT things in each case.

Comment: Do you want to do something for *each* `x` that satisfies the condition, or do something *once* if there is *an* `x` that satisfies the condition?

Comment: Bit of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass the comparison function as an argument you can use the `operator` module

```
import operator
operator.lt  #  <
operator.gt  #  >
operator.le  #  <=
operator.ge  #  >=
```

In your case you could refactor to

```
def function(comparison):
  for x in values:
    if comparison(num, 0) and comparison(x, values[0] + num):
      # do something
```

then you could call it as

```
function(operator.lt)  # positive check
function(operator.gt)  # negative check
```

Comment: thats nice for building an interpreter, but how do you use it in a normal if statment?

Comment: This would be improved by showing  how the operator functions are called.

Comment: `x < y` is equivalent to `operator.lt(x, y)`. You replace the syntactic comparison with an explicit function call.

Comment: Updated my answer to elaborate where this would be used

Comment: thats nice, but i am adding a library that probably contain 100 lines of code, instead of just using the ugly way and adding 2 more lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple code example:

```
def f(ll, nn):
   
    for i in ll:
        if ((abs(nn))==nn) and (i > (ll[0]+nn)):
            print("+",)
            
        elif ((abs(nn))!=nn) and (i < (ll[0]+nn)):
            print("-")
            
        else:
            print("*")
    


f([100,-200,300,-400], +100)
```